# open assets or raw file as File

Tags: android, file

Is there a way to open assets or raw resource as `File` ? I have method that needs open file as `File` but since i want store my file in assets or in raw folder i cannot access them.

I tried open it with `file:///android_asset/filename.xml` but received FileNotFound exception.

```
File file = new File("....");
x.load(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to open assets or raw resource as File ?

No, sorry. They do not exist as files. You can only get an `InputStream`.

Comment: Or as an AssetFileDescriptor. [Resource#openRawResourceFD][1]


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResourceFd%28int%29

Comment: where i can store file so i could access it like File ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to zip up the file first, you can do this:

```
File dir = getFilesDir();
IoUtils.extractZipResource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.texfilezip), dir, true);
File textFile = new File(dir, "textfile.txt");
```